# Sorting the Map<Key,Value> in descending order based on the value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

I am using map interface to read from a file and then store the values in that as a key value pair. The file format is as follows

```
 A 34
 B 25
 c 50
```

I will read the datas from this file and store that as a key value pair and then I will display this to the user. My requirement is to display the results in this format

```
C 50
A 34
B 25
```

Thus I need to sort the map in descending order of the value. So that I will be able to display these as my result .. I have read about this and find the below code

```
static <K,V extends Comparable<? super V>> SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K,V> map) {
        SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
                @Override public int compare(Map.Entry<K,V> e1, Map.Entry<K,V> e2) {
                    int res = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                    return res != 0 ? res : 1; // Special fix to preserve items with equal values
                }
            }
        );
        sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
        return sortedEntries;
    }
```

I hope this is gonna sort the values in ascending order, I just want to know whether this approach is correct or some other effective approach will be helpful for me ?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at Guava. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java/3420912#3420912) comment.

Comment: @NandaKumar: `Set`s doesn't allow duplicates, use for example a `List`. You break the contract of `Comparator` if you start allowing them!

Comment: ` map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e->-e.getValue())).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since you can have duplicate values you shouldn't be using a `Set` at all. Change to a `List` and sort it instead. Your `entriesSortedByValues` would look something like this:

```
static <K,V extends Comparable<? super V>> 
            List<Entry<K, V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K,V> map) {

    List<Entry<K,V>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(sortedEntries, 
            new Comparator<Entry<K,V>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Entry<K,V> e1, Entry<K,V> e2) {
                    return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
                }
            }
    );

    return sortedEntries;
}
```

*Note: in your example output the values is descending. If you want them ascending, use `e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue())` instead.*

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("A", 34);
    map.put("B", 25);
    map.put("C", 50);
    map.put("D", 50); // "duplicate" value

    System.out.println(entriesSortedByValues(map));
}
```

Output:

```
[D=50, C=50, A=34, B=25]
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Everyone looking at this should use `sortedEntries.sort()` instead of `Collections`
like that: `sortedEntries.sort((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()));`

Answer (score 14):

Write your own `comparator` and pass it to `TreeMap`

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator {

Map map;

public MyComparator(Map map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

    return ((Integer) map.get(o2)).compareTo((Integer) map.get(o1));

}
}
```

In Test Class

```
Map<String, Integer> lMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    lMap.put("A", 35);
    lMap.put("B", 25);
    lMap.put("C", 50);

    MyComparator comp=new MyComparator(lMap);

    Map<String,Integer> newMap = new TreeMap(comp);
    newMap.putAll(lMap);
```

**OutPut:**

```
C=50
A=35
B=25
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you add `lMap.put("D", 50)` since it would be considered as a duplicate (and would in fact override any other value with `50` e.g. `"C"`).

Comment: duplicate value is not allowed .

Comment: @amicngh: Thank you for your kind solution. But,I want the duplicate value to be allowed . What would be the possible way to get the same. Thank you.

Comment: The following code will work.

public Map sortByValue(Map map) {
      List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
      Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
           public int compare(Object o2, Object o1) {
                return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
               .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
           }
      });

     Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
     for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
         Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
         result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
     }
     return result;
 }

Comment: You should use new TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder());.

Map<String, Integer> newMap = new TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder());
newMap.putAll(myMap);

Comment: @NandaKumar you could add an if clause in the compareTo method on what to do if both the values are same. For e.g , here I'm ordering by keys in descending order if two values are same.         public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            if(map.get(o2) == map.get(o1))
                return o2.toString().compareTo(o1.toString());
            return ((Integer) map.get(o2)).compareTo((Integer) map.get(o1));