# Sorting pairs of numbers according to one value - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm interested in an efficient way to store pairs of numbers, and to sort them according to a value of one of the numbers. Say I have a list of numbers:

```
(1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 3), (7, 8)
```

These pairs need to be stored in some way, then sorted in descending order of the second number, such that the order of these pairs is

```
(7, 8), (3, 5), (4, 3), (1, 2)
```

What would be the Java code to achieve this? I'm aware of C++'s `std::pair`, but I was wondering about the procedure in Java.

Comment: Sorting based on Values : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647889/sorting-the-mapkey-value-in-descending-order-based-on-the-value

Comment: `Collections.sort()` using a `List<>` of your own `Tuple` class objects and a `Comparator<Tuple>`?

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup Can you please write a sample Java code that achieves this? thanks

Comment: @user506901 Yes I could, but then you wouldn't learn anything, would you?

Comment: @Anders R.Bystrup Could you please consider my update? I'm trying to achieve a descending order. Thanks

Comment: How are your "tuples" represented? An own class like `MyIntPair`, or are this small 2-element-arrays or Lists....? Or are all numbers stored in ONE "flat" 1D array or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `class pair which implements comparable interface` and use `arraylist` and `collections.sort` to sort it.

Example :-

```
public class pair implements Comparable<pair> {

            int a,b;
            @Override
            public int compareTo(pair o) {
                return(o.b-b); 
            }

            public pair(int a,int b) {

               this.a = a ;
               this.b = b;

            }

            public String toString() {
                return "("+a+","+b+")";

            }


            public static void main(String[] args) {

                 ArrayList pairs =  new ArrayList();
                 pairs.add(new pair(4,5));
                 pairs.add(new pair(7,8));
                 pairs.add(new pair(1,3));
                 Collections.sort(pairs);
                 System.out.println("sorted: "+pairs);

            }


        }
```

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup didnt see your comment sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Multimap` to store the pair (1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 3), (7, 8) as key 1 and value 2 for first pair.Then use `comparator` to sort the map according to the value of map.

Comment: And then what when you add a (1,42) tuple?

Comment: Updated @AndersR.Bystrup i guess now it will not make any pblm

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and store the values in a reverse order. so the second values of the paris will be the key of the Map.

Comment: This will get complicated if the the second value of the pairs is no longer unique. Than you would need to store lists as values of the keys.