# How can i sort ExpandableListview?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I am using one ExpndableListview with two arraylist and one Adapter.
How can I sort both child and parent arraylist data in descending order.

1.parent Arraylist

```
private List<PhoneNumber> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
```

2.child list

```
  private HashMap<String, List<SubBalance>> listDataChild = new HashMap<>();
```

And I am using Adapter code in Activity class as below :

```
        listAdapter = new ExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild, AccountProfileFragment.this);
```

ExpandableAdapter code

```
public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {

private Context context;
private List<PhoneNumber> _listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<SubBalance>> _listDataChild;
private DataSwitchListner listner;
private Activity activity;
private LoadingDialog loading;

public ExpandableAdapter(Activity activity, List<PhoneNumber> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<SubBalance>> listChildData, DataSwitchListner listner) {

    loading = LoadingDialog.getInstance();
    this.context = activity;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.listner = listner;
    this.activity = activity;
}


@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {

    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getNumber()).get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exp_child, null);
    }

    SubBalance account = (SubBalance) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    TextView currency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.currency);
    TextView balance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.balance);
    TextView expiry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expiry);
    TextView days = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.days);
    TextView daysLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.daysLabel);
    TextView lblInfinite = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblInfinite);
    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    LinearLayout llChart = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llChart);

    if (account != null && account.getCurrencyName() != null && currency != null) {

        currency.setText(account.getCurrencyName());
        balance.setText(account.getBalance());

        String expDateStr = account.getExpiryDate();
        Log.e("expDateStr12345",expDateStr);
        Date expDate;

        if (expDateStr.contains(".")) {

        /*    expiry.setText(DateUtils.convertFromOldFormatToNewFormat(expDateStr,
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_1,
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_4));*/
            expiry.setText(DateUtils.convertFromOldFormatToNewFormat(expDateStr,
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_1,
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_1));

            expDate = DateUtils.convertFromString(expDateStr, DateUtils.FORMAT_1);
            LogEvent.Log("ExpandableAdapterdate1", "Phone: " + expDate);
        } else {

            expiry.setText(DateUtils.convertFromOldFormatToNewFormat(expDateStr,
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_1_WOD,
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_1_WOD));

            expDate = DateUtils.convertFromString(expDateStr, DateUtils.FORMAT_1_WOD);
            LogEvent.Log("ExpandableAdapterdate", "Phone: " + expDate);
        }

        long daysBetween = DateUtils.daysBetween(new Date(), expDate);
        Log.e("expDateStr12345",""+daysBetween);
        int progress = 0;

        if (daysBetween > 0) {

            progress = 100;

            if (daysBetween <= 30) {

                progress = (int) ((daysBetween / 30.0) * 100);
            }
        }



        days.setTypeface(Methods.getNovaBoldItalic());
        Log.e("expDateStr12345",""+days);
        if (daysBetween > 100) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lblInfinite.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //days.setText("NO");
            days.setText("No");
            daysLabel.setText("VENCE");
            progress = 0;
        //    Log.e("expDateStr12345",""+days);
        } else {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lblInfinite.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            days.setText(Long.toString(daysBetween));
        //    Log.e("expDateStr12345",""+days.getText().toString());
        }

        progressBar.setProgress(progress);

        try {

            if (account.getIconResource() != null) {

                imgIcon.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(account.getIconResource()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getNumber()).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {

    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

    return groupPosition;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    PhoneNumber account = (PhoneNumber) getGroup(groupPosition);

    CheckBox cbxIsOn;
    FontTextView lblPhoneNumber = null;
    TextView lblBalance = null,
            lblTarrif = null,
            lblBundles = null,
            lblReload = null,
            lblAddbundle = null,
            lblHistory = null;
    LinearLayout llHeader = null;
    ImageView imgIndicator = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exp_parent1, null);
    }

    cbxIsOn = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxIsOn);
    lblPhoneNumber = (FontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblPhoneNumber);
    lblBalance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblBalance);
    lblTarrif = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblTarrif);
    lblBundles = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblBundles);
    imgIndicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIndicator);
    llHeader = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llHeader);
    lblReload = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblReload);
    lblAddbundle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblAddbundle);
    lblHistory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblHistory);

    if (isExpanded)
        llHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        llHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (account.getIsVerified().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

        cbxIsOn.setEnabled(false);

        lblTarrif.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        lblBundles.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        lblBalance.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {

        cbxIsOn.setEnabled(true);

        lblTarrif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lblBundles.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lblBalance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    lblReload.setTag(groupPosition);
    lblAddbundle.setTag(groupPosition);
    lblHistory.setTag(groupPosition);

    lblReload.setOnClickListener(this);
    lblAddbundle.setOnClickListener(this);
    lblHistory.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (account != null) {

        LogEvent.Log("Expandable Adapter", "Phone: " + account.getNumber());
        lblPhoneNumber.setText(account.getNumber());
        LogEvent.Log("Expandable Adapter", "Plan: " + account.getTariffName());
        lblTarrif.setText(account.getTariffName());
        LogEvent.Log("Expandable Adapter", "Bundle: " + account.getBundles());
        lblBundles.setText(account.getBundles());


        if (account.getCacheBalance() != null) {

            lblBalance.setText("S/ " + account.getCacheBalance());
        }

        imgIndicator.setSelected(isExpanded);

        cbxIsOn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        cbxIsOn.setChecked(account.isEnabled());
        cbxIsOn.setTag(groupPosition);

        cbxIsOn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {

    final PhoneNumber ph = (PhoneNumber) getGroup((int) view.getTag());
    final String phone = ph.getNumber();

    LogEvent.Log("Expandable Adapter", "Phone: " + ph.getNumber());
    LogEvent.Log("Expandable Adapter", "Phone Id: " + ph.getId());

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.lblReload:

            SPManager.save(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE, phone);
            SPManager.save(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE_ID, ph.getId());
            getBalances(MainActivity.FRAG_RELOAD);

            break;
        case R.id.lblAddbundle:

            SPManager.save(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE, phone);
            SPManager.save(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE_ID, ph.getId());
            getBalances(MainActivity.FRAG_PACKAGES);

            break;
        case R.id.lblHistory:

            SPManager.save(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE, phone);
            SPManager.save(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE_ID, ph.getId());
            getBalances(MainActivity.FRAG_HISTORY);

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void getBalances(final int gotoThis) {

    String currentPhoneNumber = SPManager.retrive(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE);

    try {

        QueryBuilder<PhoneNumber, Integer> qb = App.getDbHelper().getPhoneNumbersDao().queryBuilder();

        qb.where().eq("number", currentPhoneNumber);

        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = qb.queryForFirst();

        String token = SPManager.retrive(SPManager.KEY_TOKEN);
        String subId = SPManager.retrive(SPManager.KEY_CURRENT_PHONE_ID);

        MyEndpoint e = new MyEndpoint();
        e.setUrl(Urls.BASE_URL_NEW);

        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
        builder.setEndpoint(e);

        if (loading != null && !loading.isShowing()) {

            loading.showDialog(context);
        }

        eLog("Balances: " + Urls.BASE_URL_NEW + Urls.METHOD_BALANCES);
   //     eLog("Balances: " + Webservices.balance(subId, token));
        eLog("Balances: " + Webservices.balance(subId, token));
        builder.build().create(RetroClient.class).balancesWb(Webservices.balance(subId, token),
                new Callback<BalancesResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void success(BalancesResponse m, retrofit.client.Response arg1) {

                        if (loading != null && loading.isShowing()) {

                            loading.dismissDialog();
                        }

                        if (Strings.RESPONSE_SUCCESS.equalsIgnoreCase(m.getCode())) {

                            Methods.updateCurrentBalanceCurrency(m.getMain().getBalance(), m.getMain().getCurrency());

                            eLog("Sliding menu go to: " + gotoThis);

                            ((MainActivity) activity).selectSideMenu(gotoThis, true);
                        } else {

                            DialogUtil.displayAlert(context,
                                    context.getString(R.string.dialog_title_error),
                                    Strings.getError(m.getError(), context),
                                    context.getString(R.string.dialog_button_ok));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError e) {

                        eLog("Error from retrofit: " + e.getMessage());

                        if (loading != null && loading.isShowing()) {

                            loading.dismissDialog();
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    int pos = (int) buttonView.getTag();

    PhoneNumber ph = _listDataHeader.get(pos);

    _listDataHeader.get(pos).setEnabled(buttonView.isChecked());

    listner.onDataSwitched(isChecked, ph.getNumber(), ph.getSubscriberId());
}

public void eLog(String str) {

    Log.e("TAG", "" + str);
}
```

Please help me how can i sort expandableListview data in decending order
Thank you

Comment: For this you need to use comparable interface and sort your list before assigning to adapter

Comment: @Vickyexpert how did i use comparable interface in my code ?

Comment: sort listDataChild hasmap using Collections.sort() or
[try this using Comparable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647889/sorting-the-mapkey-value-in-descending-order-based-on-the-value)

Comment: @RameshPrajapati please provide me code how did i use Collection.sort() in my Above code....

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
            if (compare == 0) return 1;
            else return compare;
        }
    };
    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```