# How to Sort #HashTags count in String

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap, hashtag

**String like this:** *" My name is #shiv from #us , i watched #bahubali yesterday, #shiv is now #billgates, gate watched #bahubali in #us, #bahubali is a good #movie, #shiv is sahore #bahubali in #us";*

```
#shiv 3 times repeated
#bahubali 4 times repeated
#billgates  1 times repeated
#us  2 times repeated
#movie  1 times repeated
```

**So i want output in sorted order:**

```
#bahubali
#shiv
#us
#movie
#billgates
```

i tried code but not getting exact output:

```
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");// i converted string to String[] array
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
 System.out.println(words.length);
 for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
 if(words[i].startsWith("#"))
     list.add(words[i]); // i added all hashtags into ArrayList<String>
```

**Heare the problem is how do i count each hashtag and sorting?**

I tried with HashMap but not getting exact output:-)

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

 for ( String word : list ) {
Integer count = map.get(word);
if ( count == null ) {
   count = 0;
}
map.put(word, count  + 1);
  }
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: please format your code prior to posting.

Comment: You haven't sorted them by count, so it seems unsurprising you're not getting the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow can be thought of as the following:

1) parse the String input to identify valid words that start with '#'

2) for each valid hashtag you want to assign a frequency count

3) you want to sort keys by frequency values and output them in descending order.

Note that you don't necessarily have to loop multiple times to identify hashtags and then count their frequencies. As you iterate over tokens in the original string you can add them to your HashMap, keeping track of counts as values. You may also refer to other posts regarding how to sort by values ([Sorting the Map<Key,Value> in descending order based on the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647889/sorting-the-mapkey-value-in-descending-order-based-on-the-value)).